# RethinkDB - coerceTo("array") vs cursor performance?

Tags: cursor, rethinkdb

Consider a query, which I know will return **no more then one result**. Is there any performance penalty if instead of this:

```
r.table('users').filter({facebookUserId:facebookUserId}).
    run(connection, function(err, cursor) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cursor.toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //return the value
        });
    });
```

I use this:

```
const res = await r.table('users')
            .filter({facebookUserId:facebookUserId})
            .coerceTo("array")
            .run(connection);
```

I am specifically referring to the coerceTo() command vs the cursor.

Comment: To answer your question, `coerceTo('array')` is taking approximately 40% more time for the same result compared to `cursor.toArray()`. It's only a difference of 40ms with tens of thousands of records, but it's measurable.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

- create an index on `facebookUserId` so that I can use `r.table('users').getAll(myInput, {index: 'facebookUserId'})`, avoiding parsing all the documents (waaaaay faster)
- **not** call `sequence.coerceTo()` because it's one more step in a probably distributed, scalable DB
- use `cursor.next()` as it directly provides the next element as soon as it's ready, instead of `cursor.toArray()` which, in this case, will do the same *plus* checking the stream has ended (so it *must* be slower)
- call `cursor.close()` as soon as I enter `cursor.next()` to directly free resources
- adapt my code so that I don't even need to access an array's first element, since `cursor.next()` didn't uselessly encapsulate my document in an array

In the end:

`r.table('users').getAll(facebookUserId, {index: 'facebookUserId'})
    .run(connection, function(err, cursor) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cursor.next(function(err, item) {
            cursor.close()
            if (err) throw err;
            //do something with item instead of result[0];
        });
    });`

One more thing: `cursor.next()` behaviour can be done using `cursor.each()` with `return false`. However, should the methods vary in performance (I dont know but [a documentation note](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/next/) tends to prefer `each`), we still need to wait the return of `cursor.each()` before closing the cursor, which mustn't be the best performance profile, all things considered.

Hope this helps!